# Rails 3.1.1 escape_javacript function is rendering plain text instead of appending HTML element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

What I'm trying to do is to dynamically add form fragments inside a nested form in rails 3.1.1.
I have this javascript inside CDATA  generated from rails helper method which uses escape_javascript method.  After calling link_to 'Add Ajax' as shown below, I 'm getting plain texts instead of HTML input fields being appended.  What I really like to is have input fields are created, not plain garbage text.  Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

          var mappings='&lt;p class=\&quot;fields\&quot;&gt;\n    &lt;input id=\&quot;resource_synchronization_attributes_mappings_attributes_NEW_RECORD_source\&quot; name=\&quot;resource[synchronization_attributes][mappings_attributes][NEW_RECORD][source]\&quot; size=\&quot;30\&quot; type=\&quot;text\&quot; /&gt;\n    &lt;input id=\&quot;resource_synchronization_attributes_mappings_attributes_NEW_RECORD__destroy\&quot; name=\&quot;resource[synchronization_attributes][mappings_attributes][NEW_RECORD][_destroy]\&quot; type=\&quot;hidden\&quot; value=\&quot;false\&quot; /&gt;&lt;a href=\&quot;#\&quot; onclick=\&quot;remove_fields(this); return false;\&quot;&gt;remove&lt;\/a&gt;\n&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n\n\n'


//]]>
```

custom.js

```
replace_ids = function(s) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime()
  return s.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, new_id)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_nested_item").click(function() {
    var template = eval($(this).attr("href").replace(/.*#/, ''))
    $($(this).attr("rel")).append(replace_ids(template))
    return false
  })
})
```

application_helper.rb

```
  def generate_html(form_builder, method, options = {})
    options[:object] ||= form_builder.object.class.reflect_on_association(method).klass.new
    options[:partial] ||= method.to_s.singularize
    options[:form_builder_local] ||= :f

    form_builder.fields_for(method, options[:object], :child_index => "NEW_RECORD") do |f|
      render(:partial => options[:partial], :locals => { options[:form_builder_local] => f })
    end
  end

  def generate_template(form_builder, method, options = {})
    escape_javascript generate_html(form_builder, method, options)
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="fields">
<p>
  <%= f.label :start_datetime, "Start On" %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :start_datetime %><br />

</p>

    <% content_for :java do %>
        <%= "var mappings='#{generate_template(f, :mappings)}'" %>
    <% end %>

    <div id="mappings">
        <%= f.fields_for :mappings do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'mapping', :f => builder %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
  <%= link_to 'Add Ajax', '#mappings', :class => 'add_nested_item', :rel => '#mappings' %>


</div>
```

models

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :utilities
  has_many :people, :through => :utilities

  has_many :person_attributes

  has_one :synchronization
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :synchronization

  validates_presence_of :name


end



class Synchronization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource
  has_many :mappings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mappings,  :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:source].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  #validates_presence_of :start_datetime
end


class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :synchronization
  has_many :data, :class_name => 'PersonAttribute'
  has_many :people, :through => :data

end
```